# Rails/Devise---Password Reset & Resend Confirmation How To Redirect to Homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Using Devise 2.1.2---recently moved sign in form from dedicated sign in page to homepage. This has had a few side affects which I'm trying to figure out in the below.

1. How to change redirect on reset password instructions to go to home page, not user sign in page.
2. How to change redirect on resend confirmation instructions to go to home page, not user sign in page.
3. How to make it so users can no longer access users/sign_in page

My attempt at (1) is shown below. I'm guessing I should be able to do something similar with (2). Not quite sure how to best handle (3)---just delete view, override another devise controller, etc...

I have a production version of the website available at www.ninjaspeak.com if you want to view the behavior of the redirects yourself. Old user sign in page is at http://www.ninjaspeak.com/users/sign_in.

Following the instructions here: [Redirect URL after sending reset password instructions](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-URL-after-sending-reset-password-instructions) on git hub to try and make it so when reset passwords instructions are sent it redirects to the home page rather than the sign in page.

I created the below passwords_controller.rb file:

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  protected
  def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
    root_path
  end
end
```

And have added the following line to my routes.rb file:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :passwords => "passwords" }
```

When I run rake routes I get the following:

[image]

When I click the reset passwords instructions button I'm still getting redirected to the sign in page instead of the root page. Any thoughts on why this is?

Rails S output:

[image]

From the above it looks as if the devise passwords controller is still be used which explain why redirect is still going to user sign in page.

**Edit**

routes.rb

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users do get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' end

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :passwords => "passwords" , :confirmations => "confirmations" }
  get 'users/sign_in' => redirect("/")

  resources :langs do
    collection do
      get 'results'
    end
  end

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/about',      to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact',    to: 'static_pages#contact'
  match '/news',       to: 'static_pages#news'

end
```

passwords_controller.rb

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  protected 
  def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
    root_path
  end
end
```

confirmations_controller.rb

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
   protected
   def after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
     root_path
   end
end
```

rake routes:

```
matt@matt-desktop:~/Documents/Ruby/rails_projects/ninja_speak_app$ rake routes
          users_sign_out GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)         devise/sessions#destroy
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)         devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)     devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)    devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)           devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                  devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)          devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)             devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                  devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                  devise/registrations#destroy
       user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)     devise/confirmations#create
   new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format) devise/confirmations#new
                         GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)     devise/confirmations#show
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#new
                         POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)         devise/sessions#destroy
                         POST   /users/password(.:format)         passwords#create
                         GET    /users/password/new(.:format)     passwords#new
                         GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)    passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)         passwords#update
                         GET    /users/cancel(.:format)           devise/registrations#cancel
                         POST   /users(.:format)                  devise/registrations#create
                         GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)          devise/registrations#new
                         GET    /users/edit(.:format)             devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                  devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                  devise/registrations#destroy
                         POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)     confirmations#create
                         GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format) confirmations#new
                         GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)     confirmations#show
           users_sign_in GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)          :controller#:action
           results_langs GET    /langs/results(.:format)          langs#results
                   langs GET    /langs(.:format)                  langs#index
                         POST   /langs(.:format)                  langs#create
                new_lang GET    /langs/new(.:format)              langs#new
               edit_lang GET    /langs/:id/edit(.:format)         langs#edit
                    lang GET    /langs/:id(.:format)              langs#show
                         PUT    /langs/:id(.:format)              langs#update
                         DELETE /langs/:id(.:format)              langs#destroy
                    root        /                                 static_pages#home
                   about        /about(.:format)                  static_pages#about
                 contact        /contact(.:format)                static_pages#contact
                    news        /news(.:format)                   static_pages#news
```

Comment: If you setup a breakpoint in after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for and reset your password does it stop where you put the breakpoint ? Can you post the console log to check the redirection ? I did exactly the same thing than you few months ago and it's working

Comment: Console output added. I'll look up breakpoints tomorrow, I've never used them before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. How to change redirect on reset password instructions to go to home page, not user sign in page.

just put this in your `passwords` controller

```
protected 
def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
  root_path
end
```

---

> 2. How to change redirect on resend confirmation instructions to go to home page, not user sign in page.

create new `confirmations_controller.rb` and put this

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
   protected
   def after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
     root_path
   end
end
```

and in routes

```
 devise_for :users, :controllers => { :passwords => "passwords" , :confirmations => "confirmations" }
```

---

> 3. How to make it so users can no longer access users/sign_in page

Simple trick is to redirect the  user to the home page since your website is in production. remove the path might cause some problem so best is to do this

```
 get 'users/sign_in' => redirect("/")
```

---

### Side note:

If all you want to signin  in root page, you could have used this

```
  root :to => "devise/sessions#new"
```

---

### update

you have to remove this line from `route.rb` file

```
 devise_for :users do get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' end
 devise_for :users, :controllers => { :passwords => "passwords" , :confirmations => "confirmations" }
 get 'users/sign_in' => redirect("/")
```

and add this

```
  get 'users/sign_in' => redirect("/")
  get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :passwords => "passwords" , :confirmations => "confirmations" }
```

Comment: Still having issues after implementing above. For some reason reset password instructions still gets processed by Devise::PasswordsController and redirect still goes to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in. The same goes for resent confirmation instruction which gets processed by Devise::SessionsController and redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in. Lastly, user can still reach user/sign_in without redirect to home page occurring. Any thoughts on what might cause this? Also will edit post with my entire routes.rb file.

Comment: didn't mean Devise::SessionsController in the above but Devise::ConfirmationsController.